# How to get sharepoint admin site url?

Tags: office-365

Is there good way to get admin site url for office 365 tenant, using REST API.
Or is there any way to query site collection without admin site url?

Ideally i would like to get it only using `OAuth2` access token.

Comment: What kind of app is that?

Comment: If your O365 tenant URL is abc.sharepoint.com, your admin-url would be abc-admin.sharepoint.com. That's the way we do this.

Comment: I have multi tennant app, how do i know that my tennant url is abc.sharepoint.com?